# Get action after the specific div, with responsive height, appears on the screen

Tags: javascript

I need to make the elements inside a DIV only animated after it appears on the screen. Instead of the action happening according to the X number of page scrolling, it happens when the top of the DIV appears on the screen. The DIV has 100% of the screen height.

Follow my code at now:

```
var text_area_1 = $('.text_area_1');
var passo_img_1 = $('.passo_img_1');

var text_area_2 = $('.text_area_2');
var passo_img_2 = $('.passo_img_2');

var text_area_3 = $('.text_area_3');
var passo_img_3 = $('.passo_img_3');

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) { text_area_1.addClass("anima-left");}
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) { passo_img_1.addClass("anima-right");}

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 750) { text_area_2.addClass("anima-left");}
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 750) { passo_img_2.addClass("anima-right");}

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1150) { text_area_3.addClass("anima-left");}
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1150) { passo_img_3.addClass("anima-right");}
}
);
```

The numbers "400", "750", "1150".
They need to be in fact "Top of DIV x", "Top of DIV y", "Top of DIV z".

How do I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div#x').position().top) { text_area_1.addClass("anima-left");}
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div#x').position().top) { passo_img_1.addClass("anima-right");}

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div#y').position().top) { text_area_2.addClass("anima-left");}
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div#y').position().top) { passo_img_2.addClass("anima-right");}

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div#z').position().top) { text_area_3.addClass("anima-left");}
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('div#z').position().top) { passo_img_3.addClass("anima-right");}
    }
);
```